# Java: use Enumeration multiple times

Tags: java, enumeration

I work with `DefaultMutableTreeNode`, and it has methods `depthFirstEnumeration()`, `breadthFirstEnumeration()` and `children()` that return `Enumeration` of tree nodes.

I need to use the returned `Enumeration` multiple times, but I can't find any method like `reset()` in `Enumeration`. It seems like I only can get all the elements just once, and then call `depthFirstEnumeration()` again to get new `Enumeration`, it seems not to be a good solution.

Of course, I can get all the elements from `Enumeration` and convert it to any another reusable representation, but is there really a way to use `Enumeration` multiple times?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No that is not possible with `Enumeration`. On this subject, java doc says:

> An object that implements the Enumeration interface generates a series
>   of elements, one at a time.

Notice the **one at a time** which means that if you want to manipulate the `Enumeration` as a list then you will have to convert it.
You can create a List when you first request the `Enumeration`. This way you could use and manipulate it however you wish.

```
Enumeration e = ...
ArrayList aList = Collections.list(e);
```