# Iterate over key/values more than once in Reduce phase (HADOOP)?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, iteration, key-value, reduce

How to iterate multiple times on the key/value pairs received in Reduce phase of HADOOP. i want to do something like it, but it's not entering into the 2nd iteration.

```
for (Vector value : values)
 {

    sum += value.getVector()[length-1];
   for (int i = 1; i < length-1; i++)
     {
      value.getVector()[i]=value.getVector()[i]/value.getVector()[length-1];
      mean[i]+=value.getVector()[i];
         }
}

for (Vector value : values)
 {
    for (int i = 1; i < length-1; i++) 
           {
            value.getVector()[i]=value.getVector()[i]/value.getVector()[length-1];
           }
}
```

please give me solution ??? thnx :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are iterating over the results in `values` and once you have iterated over them then you can not do it again.

Providing the total count in `values` is not too big you could try setting the values to a local collection variable and then you should be able to iterate over them multiple times.

Try this: [Java: use Enumeration multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10460534/java-use-enumeration-multiple-times)

Comment: what if my values count is big ?

Comment: Try to code your logic so that you don't need to do multiple passes but can achieve what you want in one pass. (or map-red over the data twice with two different reducers)